# Is there any way to put customize filed in react FullCalendar?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fullcalendar, antd

I need a view like attached screenshot, and I am struggling to meet the requirements. 
Anyone could you please help? 
[image]
I have tried with [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) but I am open to any other libraries or tools.
Full code can [be found here.](https://controlc.com/5a30e43c)

```
      <FullCalendar
      customButtons= {{
        datePicker: {
          text: 'custom',
          click: function(e) {
            console.log(e)
          }
        }
      }}
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
        headerToolbar={{
          left: "title",
          right: "prev datePicker next",
        }}
        navLinks={false}
        initialView="timeGridTwoWeeks"
        views={{
          timeGridTwoWeeks: {
            type: "dayGrid",
            duration: { days: 14 },
          },
        }}
        dayHeaderContent={(args) => {
          return (
            <div className={styles.header}>
              <span className={styles.dateHeader}>
                {moment(args.date).format("DD/MM")}
              </span>
            </div>
          );
        }}
        initialEvents={INITIAL_EVENTS} // alternatively, use the `events` setting to fetch from a feed
        editable={true}
        selectable={true}
        weekends={true}
        longPressDelay={1000}
        eventLongPressDelay={1000}
        selectLongPressDelay={1000}
        allDaySlot={false}
        select={this.handleDateSelect}
        eventContent={renderEventContent} // custom render function
        eventClick={this.handleEventClick}
        eventsSet={this.handleEvents}
      />
```

Comment: You can inject content into the resource labels via the [resource render hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource-render-hooks)